# Deleting keys in new-line-delimited json

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a huge json file that looks like this:

```
{"_id": "60ddad", "type": ["test"], "company": ["60dd888"], "answers": [], "info": {}, "createdAt": "2021-07-01T11:57:08.492Z","__v": 0}
{"_id": "60deb", "type": ["test"], "company": ["60dea"], "answers": [], "info": {}, "createdAt": "2021-07-02T07:07:27.436Z","__v": 0, "sentence": {}, "text": {}}
{"_id": "60debb2", "type": ["exam"], "company": ["60dea"], "answers": ["option1"], "info": {}, "createdAt": "2021-07-02T07:07:27.451Z", "__v": 0, "sentence": {}, "text": {}}
```

When trying to upload it to a BigQuery table, it tells me that it doesn't support empty struct types ("text"). So I was thinking of simply deleting the empty struct types.

1. Is it only "text" or also "info" and "sentence" in this case?
2. How do I delete all the keys called "text", "info", "sentence" at once if every element is on a new line?

Comment: If it doesn't like "empty struct types", I can't imagine it would care what the name of the key is.

Comment: what does 'if every element is on a new line' mean?

Comment: This file does not appear to be valid JSON, although each *line* appears to be.

Comment: @ScottHunter I was thinking that once I delete the "text", "sentence" etc. it won't contain any more empty structs, so it would work. This is a sample of a .json document that containts such lines.

Comment: @LeiYang The document that I upload in BQ contains such lines, and I want to delete every "text" key such that the lines don't contain any empty structs.

Comment: your 'BigQuery table' is not accesible for us. so you may try remove them manually then prove first.

Answer (score 0):

Load the .json file; remove the empty structs; save the resulting object back to the file as JSON.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to remove all the empty structs, that's why I thought that it might be easier to just remove all the keys called "text", for example.

Comment: It might be easier (although you haven't shown *how* you would do it), but it would be a problem if any of them had a non-empty struct.